# How do I create a Selenium Webdriver test to verify an element is not present?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I am creating unit tests for my Django app in Selenium Webdriver.

I have an AJAX method that deletes a Topic from the database.
I'm trying to figure out how to verify that the deleted Topic is no longer present on the page.

I am trying to catch the Exception that the should be generated when Webdriver can't find an element:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchAttributeException

Instead I see an error:

```
*** URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Here is how I have setup the tests:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from django.utils import unittest  

class TestAuthentication(unittest.TestCase):    
    scheme = 'http'    
    host = 'localhost'    
    port = '4444'    


    def setUp(self):    
        self._driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
        self._driver.implicitly_wait(10)    

    def login_as_Kallie(self):    
        # Kallie has manual login    
        self._driver.get('http://localhost:8000/account/signin/')    
        user = self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')    
        user.send_keys("Kallie")    
        password = self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')    
        password.send_keys('*********')    
        submit = self._driver.find_element_by_id('blogin')    
        submit.click()    

    def test_Kallie_can_delete_topic(self):    
        self.login_as_Kallie()    
        self._driver.find_element_by_link_text("Topic to delete").click()    
        self._driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[3]/span[5]/a").click()    
        self._driver.find_element_by_class_name('dialog-yes').click()    
        self._driver.get("http://localhost:8000/questions/")    
        # this is the Python exception to catch: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchAttributeException    
        self.assertRaises('selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchAttributeException', self._driver.find_element_by_link_text("Topic to delete"))    

    def tearDown(self):    
        self._driver.quit()
```

How can I test that a Element of the page is absent?

Answer (score 5):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException):
    self._driver.find_element_by_link_text("Topic to delete")
```

Answer (score 4):

Except that might not work because if nothing is found,

```
driver.findElement(By.css("<css selector>"))
```

will return an NoSuchElementException which is probably the Java equivalent of the exception you are seeing.

Not sure about Python but in Java this would be better

```
assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.whateverYouWant).size() == 0)
```

or in reverse

```
assertFalse(driver.findElements(By.whateverYouWant).size() > 0)
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)

Answer (score 3):

You're catching incorrect exception. When element is not found it raises `NoSuchElementException`

```
self.assertRaises('selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException', self._driver.find_element_by_link_text("Topic to delete"))
```

Comment: The only exception I'm getting is: URLError: <urlopen error timed out>

Answer (score 2):

since the element is being deleted by an AJAX call, I would check it like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

w = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
w.until_not(lambda x: x.find_element_by_link_text("Topic to delete"))
```

This will make webdriver wait for 10 seconds until the element is NOT there. You can increase the timeout to longer than 10 seconds if you like.

Answer (score 1):

In Java what worked for me was:

```
try {
    assertNull(findElement(By.cssSelector("...")));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // its OK, as we expect this element not to be present on the site
}
```

Comment: This is java code while the question is for python and django

Answer (score 1):

```
element_you_are_looking_for = driver.find_elements_by_name("elements name")
#notice how it says "ELEMENTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"
if len(element_you_are_looking_for):
    print("element is present")
elif:
    print("element is not present")
```

or you could just do

```
if not len(element_you_are_looking_for):
    print("Element Not present!")
```

This works because if you find_elementSSSSSSSSS_by_XXXX (elements with an S, and xxxx = name,tagname,xpath,watever) and nothing is there, it just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you will do:

```
assertNotNull(driver.findElement(By.css("<css selector>")));
```

Comment: This is java code while the question is for python and django

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it could be Python.  Since your topic appears to be of type LINK_TEXT, something like this should work:

```
    for i in range(60):
        try:
            if not self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Topic to delete"): break
        except: pass
        time.sleep(1)
    else: self.fail("time out")
```

If it's of another type (i.e. XPATH), you can use the same method, but substitute the name of the link text with the location of the element on you page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one can define for detecting visible element, for django only

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class MyLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    def test_element_not_displayed(self):
        self.selenium.get('http://your_url.com')
        displayed = self.selenium.find_element_by_tag_name('table').is_displayed()

        self.assertFalse(displayed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late addition because much of the answers already here appear to be for java. The question is for python. Many of the python answers are syntactically incorrect. The correct form would involve:

```
selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 

# other code 

self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException, self._driver.find_element_by_link_text, 
 "Topic to delete")
```

This last line is basically the OPs original code but re-written in such a way as to ensure that the assertion would be executed without throwing an exception.

Comment: You probably mean semantic instead of syntax, because the syntax is fine in every answer.